# Не работает import ... в urls.py

Tags: django

Только учусь... 
Проблема такая 
[image: ошибка при запуске сервера]

Как итог - учусь по курсу(в курсе у тренера Django 1.11 - у меня стоит Django 2.2)
Собственно вот и приходится плясать с бубном... Подскажите пожалуйста - почему общий импорт не работает в версии 2.2 ??
[image: urls.py]

Comment: покажите этот `urls.py` (с `lesson_fifth`)

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0  только так смог - скрином. Еще не разобрался с сайтом

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 временно нашел решение... прописал построчно... Но суть остается

Comment: Ну в файле всё норм, вроде. Попробуйте удалить первую строку вообще, может. Может, где-то русская буква у вас прописана в импорте?)

Comment: Отсюда скопируйте-вставьте импорт https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path

Comment: Выкиньте этот протухший курс куда-нибудь подальше и возьмите что-то посвежее - больше толку будет

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0   вся прелесть в том что оно то работает. Но если закоментить все from и раскоментить первую строку - работать не будет...(((

Comment: @andreymal курс хороший - доходчиво объясняют. Сделан курс на конец 18 года(довольно свежий). Только непонятно почему на 1.11 - ведь в это время уже были 2.0 Вот и приходится танцевать с бубном. Кстати если есть рекомендации -  прислушаюсь к вашему мнению, ибо есть с чем сравнивать... По Джанго 2.0 не видел еще курсов вообще...

Comment: Между версиями 1.1 и 1.11 - разница ДЕСЯТЬ лет! Исправьте версию в тексте вопроса, курс на 1.11 - хороший и не протухший, а вы в вопросе почему-то 1.1 написали

Comment: По теме вопроса — непонятно, что вы вообще хотели строчкой `import...` сделать, это синтаксически некорректный и бессмысленный код. Может, в этом вашем курсе таким образом просто скрыли список импортов, чтобы пример портянками импортов не перегружать?

Comment: @Дмитрий так а что вы импортировать собрались через `import ...`? Учите мат часть.

Comment: @andreymal судя по данным которые говорились не в одном курсе - таким образом импортируются ВСЕ файлы джанго. Для того что бы не прописывать каждый в отдельной строке - используют import ... Так было по крайней мере в 1.11 (пару раз сталкивался с этим) - но у меня эта команда ни разу не зашла...Постоянные проблемы

Comment: Подразумеваю все библиотеки и т.п.

Comment: @Дмитрий используют только в тексте курса, чтобы экономить место. С точки зрения пинового кода это полный бред, и вы должны писать все импорты целиком как положено. Импорта ВСЕХ файлов, во-первых, не существует в принципе (ни в каких версиях Django и Python), а во-вторых, даже если бы и сущестовало бы — это было бы очень тупо, потому что замедлило бы производительность и замусорило бы пространство имён

Comment: @andreymal,@ m0nte-cr1st0 я понял вас. Создаю новый вопрос - по этому поводу. Не идет обучение - засел на ровном месте... Огромное спасибо за участие

Comment: имею ввиду - с этим вопросом понятно... Появились другие...